# style for the view poping up in the webview when a user selects a combo box

Tags: android, styles

I need to find what style/theme is used by the webview for the view that pops when the user clicks a combo box in the html page.

[image]

On certain phones, the text gets chopped and I need to reduce the text size or allow each line to span multiple lines.

I have tried 5 styles so far, without success:

```
<style name="teststyle1" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/another_btn_radio</item>
</style>

<style name="teststyle2" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/another_btn_radio</item>
</style>

<style name="teststyle3" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/another_btn_radio</item>
</style>

<style name="teststyle4" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/another_btn_radio</item>
</style>

<style name="teststyle5" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/another_btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait a second ... maybe I am missing something here but you said "... pops when the user clicks a combo box in ***the html page***." Why would you look at ANDROID styling (xml files), if this is on an HTML page (css, html)?

Comment: The call made by HTML invokes a native view. If you check the screen shot, you can see this is a native picker.

Comment: Do you have an URL for a page that uses that combo box? I am not seeing the native picker that you have on the screenschot on some HTML pages with combo box that I tried with the standard emulator. Is it possible that your phone has implemented a special handling for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `AndroidManifest.xml` at the `<activity>` tag for whichever activity those screens are from.  Under the `android:theme` property is where you set the theme, or in this case find out what the current one is!  It looks like it might be `Theme.Dark` but I'm not sure off the top of my head

Or if you're just trying to change the list items in that view to fit the title, a change of font size is all you need.  You can set it in the layout or  programmatically in the Activity with:

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById('R.id.your_view');
view.setTextSize(12);
// ^^^ will set font size to 12dp, you can use 'setTextSize(pt,12)' for different units
```

I'd look at `AndroidManifest.xml` and look at the activity's theme, it looks like it's a system styling.  Source:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

---

#### More Links to look at

---

- [Set spinner within custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673717/set-spinner-within-custom-dialog)
- [Android: Where is the Spinner widget's text color attribute hiding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding)
- [Android - Customizing the Spinner widget Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177700/android-customizing-the-spinner-widget-look-and-feel)

---

#### Another Stab At This

---

Is this project on Github?  Could you post your logic for the registration `view`?

Comment: I need the style or a way to find what style is used. I do not have a direct access to the view, since it is the webview that is launching that view.

Comment: You can look in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, find the `<activity>` tag that belongs to the `Activity` that the `WebView` is in and see if they have a theme specified with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dark`.  So it may look something like this: `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dark">`.

Comment: I also did some digging around for you and found the XML for the Gingerbread Dark Theme.  Hope this helps:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/724ffc36583ad81d33c5d4d2057ed12eece719ad/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: I need something along the lines of @android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner, but I can't put my finger on it :(. Appreciate the effort here JustLikeThat.

Comment: So wait, you want to add a `Spinner` to show loading?  Or you need to change the attributes of `@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner`?  Could you refine your question and append it as an update, please? (what you've done, what you still need or need that you didn't know about)  I'll post some more links for you to look at too...

Comment: Appreciate your effort here JustLikeThat. Thank you! We ended giving up on trying to fix this for now.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm sorry I haven't posted anything else on this recently, I hadn't seen the update to your post with the styles you've tried.  I'll see if I can figure something out for you in the mean time :)

Answer (score 1):

Allow Multiple lines would be better.
If you only set the size.
It would be changed if you want to add some words sometime.

Answer (score 1):

This change is actually going to be done on the HTML side of things not in android.  Use the webkit-appearance CSS tag to specify an appearance style then you can work with the wrapping using CSS.

URL: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance

Comment: It is a native Dialog. Not HTML based dialog so styles won't help here.